How to process and archive S3 files with timestamp appended in IICS
my source is S3 and fiiicsles are appended with timestamp and the file format is csv. I want to read the data from the file and archive it.
For example : my s3 path s3-abc-asia1/datalake/landing/sample_file_12042024120322.csv. tomorrow new file arrives with new timestamp
How to process in iics

You can do this but you have to follow below steps.

Setup your secure agent so that it can read/write from S3.
Follow below link to setup secure agent to run command task - batch or shell script.
create a CMD task to call a script to download files from S3. And then create a file list with that file(s). Please note, if you dont find any files, you can process empty files.

ls -1 sample_file*.csv> sample_file_list.lst


Use your normal mapping to read the data using file list. Please note to use indirect file read method.
Use another command task to zip and archive in S3.

cat sample_file_list.lst | while read line ; do zip $line.zip $line ; done

A lot of steps are mentioned in this link https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/data-integration/current-version/taskflows/taskflows/setting-taskflow-step-properties/command-task-step.html

I'd use Mass Ingestion to get the files from S3. It's better from monitoring perspective than CMD task. And fits nicely into a taskflow.
